# understanding of object definition: className objName = (className) objName.methodName()

Tags: c#

I can't understand what does "(HttpWebResponse)" refers to in the code line below:

```
HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
```

Does that angular brackets mean something about inheritance?

this question is about c#.net

Comment: this is a type-cast http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx (look for explicit conversion)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Answer (score 0):

These are regular brackets or parentheses. When there's a class name between them before a function call like `WebReq.GetResponse()`, it means that the result of the function call will be cast as that class (or type).

[GetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an object of type [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a super-type of [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx)